# Range of convergence of $\sum_1^{\infty}x^n+\frac{1}{3^nx^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need help figuring out for which $x$ the series:

$$\sum_1^{\infty}x^n+\frac{1}{3^nx^n}$$

converges.

I think it's easy to see that for $x\ge1$ and $x\le-1$ the series diverges.

For $-1\lt x \lt 1$ I tried using d'Alembert theorem but that was messy and got me to a wrong answer.

The answer is: $\frac{1}{3}\lt |x| \lt 1$

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Convergent_because_L_.3C_1

Comment: Just split the series into two series. Study each series, the range of convergence of the original series should belong to the intersection of the range of convergence of the two series.

Comment: In order for $\sum_1^{\infty}\left(x^n+\frac{1}{3^nx^n}\right)$ to converge, you need $x^n+\frac{1}{3^nx^n}$ to go to zero.  For what $x$ is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What is the range of convergence of $\sum x^n$ ?
- What is the range of convergence of $\sum 1/(3^nx^n)$ ?

Then you know that

- The sum of two convergent series is convergent
- The sum of a convergent and a divergent series is divergent.

Is it enough to conclude ?